# How to return different results for the same query in Express.js with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express.js and I'm wondering how to return different results with the same query based on different logics. Here is my code:

```
const { Student } = require('../mongoose-models/student');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/students/', async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.query;
  const studentsList = await Student.find(query);

  if (!studentsList) return res.status(404).send('No student found.');
  res.send(studentsList);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Now, if I go to `http://localhost:3000/api/students/age=20` in my browser, then it will return a list of all students that are exactly 20 in a json format (the student data is stored in MongoDB). Now, I want to implement another function that will return a list of students younger than 20 when specifying age=20. Is this possible to add this logic within the same block and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In express for same GET request with dynamic parameter we have

```
router.get('/api/students/:dynamicVariable', async (req, res) => {
    // you can pass multiple parameter in url 
    const query = req.params.dynamicVariable
    // for access then use req.params.paramsNameInUrl with ":" in from of variable
})
```

This is wrong way to query from database But it help for big logic

```
router.get('/api/students/query=:Query', async (req, res) => {
  const query = req.params.Query;
  const studentsList = await Student.find(query);
  if (!studentsList) 
    return res.status(404).send('No student found.');
  res.send(studentsList);
});
```

Your query in Postman or url

```
www.your-domin.com/api/students/query={"age": 20 }
// or query based on your requirement
query={"status":true}
query={"age": { $gt: 20 } } 
query={"age": {$nin: [20, 30, 13]}}
```

use GET Request if using Post